# Converting JSON Array Entries to XML

Tags: c#, json.net

I wanted to convert the JSON data into XML contains the JSON array entries into the same. JSON data which I am converting is as below

```
{
   "userName":[
      "user1",
      "user2"
   ],
   "referenceNumber":"098784866589157763",
   "responseCode":"00",
   "responseDesc":"Success."
}
```

To convert the JSON to XML using below C# code

```
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonData, "response");
```

which is converting JSON to below XML

```
<response>
    <userName>user1</userName>
    <userName>user2</userName>
    <referenceNumber>098784866589157763</referenceNumber>
    <responseCode>00</responseCode>
    <responseDesc>Success.</responseDesc>
</response>
```

but expected output XML is as below

```
<response>
    <userName>
        <element>user1</element>
        <element>user2</element>
    </userName>
    <referenceNumber>098784866589157763</referenceNumber>
    <responseCode>00</responseCode>
    <responseDesc>Success.</responseDesc>
</response>
```

Is there any way to achieve the same?

Comment: You have to transform it manually. _please_ avoid using the extremely dated `System.Xml.XmlDocument` family of APIs and use the modern `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` apis that will save you many headaches as you implement your transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview), which is elegant way to manipulate XML documents, then 
 below is one of the ways to achieve the requirement:

```
   XElement root = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(jsonData, "response").Root;

       // Create elements for userName in new XML
   var docFinal = new XDocument(new XElement("response" , new XElement("userName",            
                  from user in root.Descendants("userName") select new XElement("element", user.Value))));

        //Add remaining XML Attributs
   docFinal.Root.Add(root.Elements()
                   .Select(x => new XElement(x.Name, x.Value)).Where(x => x.Name != "userName"));

        //OUTPUT 
        //<response>
        //  <userName>
        //    <element>user1</element>
        //    <element>user2</element>
        //  </userName>
        //  <referenceNumber>098784866589157763</referenceNumber>
        //  <responseCode>00</responseCode>
        //  <responseDesc>Success.</responseDesc>
        //</response>
```

Comment: Just use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(jsonData, "response").Root`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXNode_1.htm) not `XElement.Parse(JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonData, "response").InnerXml)` -- you're deserializing to an `XmlDocument` then formatting and parsing again to an `XDocument`.